# django too many values to unpack error

Tags: python, django, django-views

i have stored a list in django and now i want to convert that list to query set .

```
ques=list(sorted(Upload.objects.filter(unique_id=tdetail), key=lambda x: random.random()))

    platform=Platform()


    platform.user=request.user
    platform.test_key=article
    platform.list=ques
    platform.save()
```

ques is the list which i have stored in database..
it is the list of questions in random pattern . not to access the same questions in that pattern i am using this.
now when i am using it to convert it into a query set

```
platform=get_object_or_404(Platform,user=request.user,test_key=article)

ques=Upload.objects.get(platform.list)
```

it gives the error as...
   arg, value = filter_expr
ValueError: too many values to unpack

I want to access it in template..as {{ques.0.field}}

Comment: You're missing some model definitions above, and your .get is missing a named parameter (like `platforms=platform.list)`. That said, you should in general think of what the sql is doing. If you had all of this right, you're where clause is asking your sql engine to match two lists exactly. I don't think that's what you are after. Moreover, I don't know why you need to go get "Upload" because you already (I think?) have all the "Uploads"
 (again, guessing because I haven't seen any models) in platform.list. So in the template it would be platform.list.0.field (or whatever).

Comment: thnkyou james for you valuable help ......but ill tell you what exactly i am trying to do.....so....i have a list of questions  in my database which has fields question,option1,option2,option3...so on......and I want to display random questions for all users.........so the approach that i am using is ...i am randomly displaying the question for the first time the user runs the method then i am storing that list in the database...so when the user refreshes the page it'll look in the database if the pattern exist it has to read that pattern...rather than creating a new set of random questions

Comment: i used your approach and added a parameter like   ques=Upload.objects.filter(slug=platform.list).....and now when i print it in template...i get....<QuerySet []> ....a blank query set

Comment: so again though, what you describe is just platform.list. So why not just use that directly after you have saved it like I said?